# Putting a value filter on pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to duplicate some excel functionality in pandas and we have a huge pivot table upon which we do numerous operations that are very slow.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
import pandas as pd

Data = [["NonLin1", "NestleBig-100", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_10", 435, 1.4],
["NonLin1", "NestleBig-100", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_11", 743, 1.3],
["NonLin1", "NestleBig-101", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_10", 542, 1.5],
["NonLin1", "NestleBig-101", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_11", 324, 1.2],
["NonLin1", "NestleBig-102", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_10", 243, 1.8],
["NonLin1", "NestleBig-102", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_11", 444, 1.2],
["NonLin2", "NestleSmall-100", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_10", 655, 1.0],
["NonLin2", "NestleSmall-100", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_11", 252, 1.3],
["NonLin2", "NestleSmall-101", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_10", 435, 1.1],
["NonLin2", "NestleSmall-101", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_11", 542, 1.3],
["NonLin2", "NestleSmall-102", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_10", 645, 1.5],
["NonLin2", "NestleSmall-102", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_11", 435, 1.1],
["NonLin3", "NestleBig-100", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_10", 653, 1.2],
["NonLin3", "NestleBig-100", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_11", 435, 1.4],
["NonLin3", "NestleBig-101", "daily", "unsolved", "NestleBig", "v10_10", 875, 1.4],
["NonLin3", "NestleBig-101", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_11", 214, 1.5],
["NonLin3", "NestleBig-102", "daily", "solved", "NestleBig", "v10_10", 890, 1.2],
["NonLin3", "NestleBig-102", "daily", "unsolved", "NestleBig", "v10_11", 432, 1.5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ["ProblemClass", "inputID", "profile", "Status", "TestID","runID", "NofIters", "time"])

pivottab = pd.pivot_table(data=df, index=["ProblemClass", "inputID",  "Status", "TestID","runID"], values=['time'], aggfunc={'count'})

pivottab.columns = list("#")  #Can we rename this column white creating the pivot table itself?
```

The pivot table itself is fine and looks like this

[image: pivot table from pandas dataframe]

But  I want to highlight the rows where v10_11 and v10_10 produce different results for Status. as in filter the pivot table further to only see those rows where the statuses differ. In the excel pivot table, we can put a value filter on Status and choose  value filter on (#) != 2 but I am wondering how to filter this pivot table further. I would like to do operations on this pivot table as it will be easier and I would like to exclude these from the pivot table for further analysis. But any other options are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a pivot table with (or without) the selected data, you can pre-filter the dataframe first and create the pivot table afterwards. One possible approach to do it would be:

- Using the [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) method, remove all data from the original table, where there are no duplicate rows along this column set: `['ProblemClass', 'inputID', 'TestID', 'Status']`
- Create a pivot table from the pre-filtered data

**Example**

- Pivot table without the highlighted data

```
pre_filtered_data = df[df.duplicated(subset=['ProblemClass', 'inputID', 'TestID', 'Status'], keep=False)]
pivottab = pd.pivot_table(data=pre_filtered_data, index=["ProblemClass", "inputID",  "Status", "TestID", "runID"], values=['time'])
```

Output:

```
                                                      time
ProblemClass inputID         Status TestID    runID       
NonLin1      NestleBig-100   solved NestleBig v10_10   1.4
                                              v10_11   1.3
             NestleBig-101   solved NestleBig v10_10   1.5
                                              v10_11   1.2
             NestleBig-102   solved NestleBig v10_10   1.8
                                              v10_11   1.2
NonLin2      NestleSmall-100 solved NestleBig v10_10   1.0
                                              v10_11   1.3
             NestleSmall-101 solved NestleBig v10_10   1.1
                                              v10_11   1.3
             NestleSmall-102 solved NestleBig v10_10   1.5
                                              v10_11   1.1
NonLin3      NestleBig-100   solved NestleBig v10_10   1.2
                                              v10_11   1.4
```

- Pivot table with the highlighted data (simply revert the filtering condition using `~`)

```
pre_filtered_data = df[~df.duplicated(subset=['ProblemClass', 'inputID', 'TestID', 'Status'], keep=False)]
pivottab = pd.pivot_table(data=pre_filtered_data, index=["ProblemClass", "inputID",  "Status", "TestID", "runID"], values=['time'])
```

Output

```
                                                      time
ProblemClass inputID       Status   TestID    runID       
NonLin3      NestleBig-101 solved   NestleBig v10_11   1.5
                           unsolved NestleBig v10_10   1.4
             NestleBig-102 solved   NestleBig v10_10   1.2
                           unsolved NestleBig v10_11   1.5
```

---

Explanation

- `df.duplicated(subset=['ProblemClass', 'inputID', 'TestID', 'Status'], keep=False)` is used to find all rows duplicated for the given columns. For your data, the only rows that won't have such duplicates are the rows, where the values for `['ProblemClass', 'inputID', 'TestID']` are the same, but the `'Status'` value is different
- the expression above is used as a mask to remove rows that are unique in this regard, meaning multiple results were achieved for the `'Status'` column